# TypeError: e.filter is not a function

Tags: mern

A mono repo MERN stack, where I set up a filter and a context. Locally, no errors. But after deployment, the console tells me ".filter is not a function"? Yet "posts" is an array! Thanks to the one who can help me :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../context";
import Card from "./Card";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const { posts } = useAppContext();

  const [searchTerm, setSearchterm] = useState("");

  const handleSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchterm(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-2 ">
      <input
        placeholder="Recherche par nom..."
        type="search"
        className="border-[#526DFE] text-white border-2 border-solid rounded-lg px-2 py-2 bg-transparent "
        required=""
        onChange={handleSearchTerm}
      />

      <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4 text-center  justify-center bg-black py-4 ">
        {posts
          .filter((post) => {
            return searchTerm.toLowerCase() === ""
              ? post
              : post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
          })
          .map((post, index) => (
            <Card
              key={index}
              _id={post._id}
              title={post.title}
              description={post.description}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```